# Can I open ClearCase vtree with only some branches expanded by default?

Tags: branch, clearcase, version-tree

We have a ton of branches in our VOB.
Some files change very frequently, and so the version tree is a mess.

Most of the time, I only care about one particular branch and its subbranches.
I know I can collapse certain branches once the VTree is open, but that gets very tedious.

Is there any way to open the VTree with most branches collapsed (hidden) except for the ones I care about?

Answer (score 0):

Even in its latest iteration (ClearCase 9.0), [`cleartool lsvtree -graph`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm) don't offer much in term of filtering.

You do have the `-bra/nch branch-pname` option though:

> Starts the version tree listing at the specified branch.
>   You can also use an extended name as the `pname` argument (for example, `foo.c@@\main\bug405`) to start the listing at a particular branch

Combined with the `-g/raphical` (which starts a Version Tree Browser for each element you specify as an argument), you can launch a VTree (GUI) directly on the right branch.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  Only thing is, we typically only bring up Vtree from ClearCase Explorer.  I haven't seen an option to do that in there.  Sounds like it's only possible from the command line.

Comment: @livefree75 I agree, but I mentioned the command-line option because it is more complete than launching the VTree with the GUI: you can add options that might interest you in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to lock -obsolete any branch instances you don't use anymore. They will drop off the graphical vtrees as long as the option to display obsolete versions isn't enabled.

Comment: Oh, if you lock the unused brtypes obsolete, all instances will "disappear" unless you enable display of "obsolete" items.

Comment: This might work for some of our very old branches.  Thanks.